# Unless current user is one of the users who belong to a record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Walls have many users through WallAssignments

```
has_many :users, :through => :wall_assignments
```

Users have many walls through WallAssignments

```
has_many :wall_assignments
has_many :walls, :through => :wall_assignments
```

I want to redirect away from `walls#show` unless the user belongs to the wall.

So far I have this

```
unless @wall.user_id == current_user.id
    redirect_to current_user
end
```

The problem is, this is finding the creator of the wall. I want to allow all users who belong to the wall to view the wall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if @wall.users.include?(current_user)
  # redirect to wall view
end
```